# Safari version of chrome://media-internals

Tags: google-chrome, safari, http-live-streaming, fairplay

Is there something similar to chrome://media-internals for Safari? I'm working on HLS/SAMPLE-AES fMP4 stream and video "MEDIA_ERR_DECODE" is not really helpful. I'm hoping to find some tool that can inspect the stream closely and give a little bit more info on why decoding / decryption is failing...